# Question/Answer mismatch

Tags: discussion

The selected answer to this question (as well as the number of upvotes) makes no sense;  It seems to just represent people's love for alcohol stoves.  While alcohol has upsides, the problem here is that the answer doesn't actually address the question at all (the op is asking about petrol variants).  The problem of course is that the question has been completely re-written after the answer was created.  Thoughts on how we can clean this up?  [What's the difference between white gas, propane, kerosene, and gasoline?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/31/whats-the-difference-between-white-gas-propane-kerosene-and-gasoline)

Comment: Personally, I'd edit the question slightly, to cover the scope of the accepted answer.

Comment: I think this is a growing issue. People need to keep in mind that the core idea of this site is to answer the question being asked. Not answer with related problems. Concentrate on what the OP wanted. That said it's also the askers responsibility to make the actual question clear.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed - the accepted answer doesn't answer the question.

I think the best answer is to ask the OP to answer the question.

If no response, we could move his post to a comment (minor wording tweak needed to fit in a comment)